# Can $cos^{-1}(b/cos(x)) $simplify? ( besides of course $1/\cos = \sec$)

Tags: trigonometry

Can $ cos^{-1}(\frac{b}{\cos(x)})$ simplify?

( besides of course 1/cos = sec)
  it seems like it should simplify, but I just can see how.

Comment: Have you tried WolframAlpha? Have you tried simplifying $\arccos(\frac1{\cos(x)})$? Did you look at the graphs to see if you recognize things? Did you compute a few values? If you did some work, show us. If you didn't, do so before you post.

Comment: Welcome, DavidK. This is a reasonable question. Note, first of all, that since $|\cos(x)|\le 1$, unless $|b|\le 1$, the quotient will always be too large to be cosine of anybody. But even if $|b|$ is tiny, it will only be defined for certain ranges of $x$. I, for one, do not know of any formula for simplifying this. Even if $\cos x = 1/2$, what can you do with $\arccos(2b)$ for $|b|\le 1/2$?